# Why is the derivative of f equal to the sum of its partials along its components?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, derivatives, partial-derivative, analytic-functions

I was trying to understand the development of the solution in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2654583/890534), where $\overline{f(z)}f'(z)dz = (u - iv)(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial v}{\partial y})(dx + idy)$. The first term is pretty obvious, as it is just the conjugate. However, where does the equality

$$f'(z)dz = \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right)(dx + idy)$$
come from?

I know that we can write the derivative of an analytic function $f$ as

$$f'(z) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} + i \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$

but the above term does not seem to follow algebraically. Where does this term come from?

Comment: because $dz = dx + i dy$, so it *does* follow algebraically

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen - my question was where the first part comes from, as the partials aren't the same in the second equation. However, I figured out it was due to a Cauchy-Riemann substitution of partials. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This comes from the Cauchy-Riemann equations, since $f$ is analytic:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$

so it follows from my second expression.